# Cool Commands plugin for Visual Studio 2005

Tags: plugins, visual-studio-2005

A recent hard-drive crash wiped my development environment at work, and until then, I never realised how much I had grown to depend on a couple of the functions in the Cool Commands plugin.

Despite my many and varied protestations, we are still languishing on VS2005, and it appears that all links to the Cool Commands plugin (for Visual Studio 2005) have disappeared from the internet.

Does anyone know if it is still available (from a reputable and virus free source of course)?

Answer (score 0):

Found it [here](http://download.deklarit.com/files/gmilano/CoolCommands30.msi), linked from the developer's weblog [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gmilano/archive/2006/05/10/446010.aspx)

It went away for a while, but it appears to be back